# Putting image in image view according to entered text

Tags: android

I have image views at runtime and alphabet images in drawable. i want that when user enter some text in edit text then whatever he entered in edit text checks the alphabet and put only that alpbhabet images in views....

if its possible then help thanks in advance
below is my code to put imageview at runtime.....

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str=text.getText().toString();
              int num= str.length(); 
              //generating image view at runtime
              ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[num];
              for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
              {   count=count+1;
                  imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            imageViewArray[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.back_view);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                60,60);
                lp.leftMargin=left;
                lp.topMargin=top;
                    rl.addView(imageViewArray[i],lp);
                    imageViewArray[i].setId(count); 
                      left=left+70;
              }
              }
        });
```

Comment: What is the output of the above code? What happens / what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `array` of images of alphabets (make sure they are in order A-Z). You loop through each character in the string already. Just get the position of the `alphabet` in the array as follows:

```
int alphabetPosition = str.charAt(i) - (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)) ? 'A' : 'a');
```

then set the image as follows:

```
imageViewArray[i].setImageResource(photos[alphabetPosition]);
```

So final code will look like this:

```
...
...
for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
{   count=count+1;
    imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    int alphabetPosition = str.charAt(i) - (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i)) ? 'A' : 'a');
    imageViewArray[i].setImageResource(photos[alphabetPosition]);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my way. You got drawable like a below and set to ImageView:

```
 Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
              .getIdentifier(edit_text.getText(), "drawable", getPackageName()));
 imageView.setImageResource(drawable);
```

You can add this into for loop and achieve what you want. If i am not think wrong then this solution works.

Comment: there should be imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

Comment: what do i haVE TO PUT in place of "drawable"  we cant put drawable as string

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve it like this.

1. set `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` to edittext, so you will given with a callback method as soon user does changes in edittext.
2. look for what action user has performed(entered character, deleted character,pressed some other button other entering or deleting characters).
3. have a swich case statement to set the images views. or best option i would prefer is get the character what user has entered then use follwing code get the proper drawable using below code.

> getResources().getIdentifier("a","drawable","packagename");

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText ed1;
Button b1;
ImageView img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str=ed1.getText().toString();
            if(str.equals("A"))
            {

                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
            }
            else if(str.equals("B"))
            {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

This is the code as what u needed.. simple code.. change it to your modification accordingly... +1 if u like it..

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Text Watcher,
  // Get the Reference of EditText

```
                        // Attach TextWatcher to EditText
                        editText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

// EditTextWacther  Implementation

```
            private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                {
                            // When No Password Entered
                           textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("Not Entered");
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {

                }

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {
                             if(s.equals("A"))
                                   //set Image 

                             else  if(s.equals("B"))
                                   //set Image 

                             //so on

                }
        };
```

Comment: i dont want to print only a single character. iwant to check whole word like"APPLE" and view images according to it in randomly

Comment: istead of this 

get two arrays one of list of images and another would be your string like example ok
now  instead of if(s.equals("A"))
                                   //set Image 

                             else  if(s.equals("B"))
                                   //set Image 

put images and string in same order

Comment: like array of string's first string is Apple then put apple image id in first position of array of images

Comment: there just need to iterate,
if you tip apple
then from list of string find out the position of apple

Comment: use that position to get you image from list of images

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] str = {APPLE,BANANA};
Drawable[] d = {"id of apple image", "id of banana image"};


private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {
                        // When No Password Entered
                       textViewPasswordStrengthIndiactor.setText("Not Entered");
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                        int position = -1;
                        for(i=0;i<str.length;i++){
                           if(s==str[i])
                             position = i;

                            }

                           if(position!=-1)
                                img.setimg(d[position]);

            }
    };
```

Comment: how could u make string "str" ad array "str[]"

Comment: wait i will drop a demo

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> strArray = new ArrayList<String>();
int[] drawableArray ={R.drawable.red_apple,R.drawable.banana};
ImageView img;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    strArray.add("APPLE");


    //dArray.add(R.drawable.red_apple);
    //dArray.add(R.drawable.red_apple);
//  dArray.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    et.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);

     img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
      {
                  // When No Password Entered
      }

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
      {

      }

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
      {
          int position =-1;
          for (int i = 0; i < strArray.size(); i++) {
              Log.e(""+s.toString(), ""+strArray.get(i).toString());
              if(s.toString().equals(strArray.get(i).toString())){
               position = i;
              }
              Log.e("", ""+position);
              if (position!=-1) {
                  Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(drawableArray[position]);
                  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableArray[position]); 
   //                     img.setImageDrawable(d);
                  img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }



      }
  };

}
```

and xml is

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="APPL" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_below="@id/et"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:background="@drawable/red_apple" />
```

Comment: add me in google chat my id is "satyamaan@gmail.com"

Comment: put logs and check what is happening and let know the result so that i can help you more, it works for me but anyways please let me know what is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.textwatcherwithimage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> strArray = new ArrayList<String>();
int[] drawableArray ={R.drawable.ic_launcher};
ImageView img;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    strArray.add("APPLE");


    //dArray.add(R.drawable.red_apple);
    //dArray.add(R.drawable.red_apple);
//  dArray.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
    et.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);

     img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
//       img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_apple);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

  private final TextWatcher  mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
      {
                  // When No Password Entered
      }

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
      {

      }

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
      {
          int position =-1;
          for (int i = 0; i < strArray.size(); i++) {
              Log.e(""+s.toString(), ""+strArray.get(i).toString());
              if(s.toString().equals(strArray.get(i).toString())){
               position = i;
              }
              Log.e("", ""+position);
              if (position!=-1) {
                  Drawable d =     getResources().getDrawable(drawableArray[position]);
                  Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
//                    img.setImageDrawable(d);
                  img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }

                         //set Image 


                         //set Image 

                   //so on

      }
  };

}
```

find this,
here if i have apple string then i display ic_launcher or else nothing.
you can try to modify array according to your requirement